# ReadJson not called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

What I want to achieve. I have a class that has some properties/objects in it. I want to serialize only those objects which meet the CanConvert condition with my custom serializer, others should be handled defaultly.

Problem is that with `[JsonConverter(typeof(UnityObjectConverter))]` it serializes correctly but deserialization fails. Probably because I save only path to the object, not the whole object and when some internal check (which I don't get why) occurs than it fails and returns null, because the `ReadJson` is never called.

When I use Settings, it causes more problems to me, that it solves because it does not serialize the rest. I don't want to have serialization for the whole class, because that way it wouldn't be very universal since several objects inherit that class. The class itself is not abstract so there might be some objects using just the class. I would be really glad if someone could help. Thanks

```
 public class UnityObjectConverter : JsonConverter {

public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
    Debug.Log(objectType.BaseType == typeof(UnityEngine.Object));
    return objectType.BaseType == typeof(UnityEngine.Object);
}

public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
    Debug.Log("read");
    return UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(reader.ReadAsString(), objectType);
}

public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
    Debug.Log("write");
    var item = (UnityEngine.Object)value;
    writer.WriteValue(UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(item));
    writer.Flush();
}

public override bool CanRead {
    get {
        return true;
    }
}

public override bool CanWrite {
    get {
        return true;
    }
}
 }
```

Example of property

```
 /// <summary>
    /// GameObject if item is needed to be visualised
    /// </summary>
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnityObjectConverter))]
    public GameObject gameObject { get { return _gameObject; } private set { _gameObject = value; } }
    protected GameObject _gameObject = null;
```

Example of de/serialization

```
public static void Add(Item i) {
        items.Add(i);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Application.dataPath + DATA_PATH))
            System.IO.File.Create(Application.dataPath + DATA_PATH).Close();
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(Application.dataPath + DATA_PATH)) {
            sw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items));
        }
    }

static void Load() {
        items.Clear();
        Item[] it = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item[]>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + DATA_PATH));
        if (it != null)
            items.AddRange(it);
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the deserialized string is correct? Have you checked the file at the path?

Comment: The string is valid and it looks ok. The path pretty much has no choice but to be valid :) (I checked it too ofc) problem is that it never gets to the point where it could even check it is valid. I have Debug.Log("read"); in the ReadJson method and thanks to it I know that it isn't ever called.

Comment: Perhaps it's `CanConvert` that's causing this. Could it be that since you write a string value (the path), it deserializes as a string and is of type String?

Comment: That was my first idea, but it never gets called either. It seems that json.net never calls it when using [JsonConverter(typeof(UnityObjectConverter))] attribute. It was called when I used JsonSerializerSettings, but than I had issues with converting everything else.

Comment: Do you think you could edit your question and add the code where you call Serialize and Deserialize? It also sounds like you're serializing some class of yours - if so, could you show it?

Comment: Edited... I haven't included whole class that I try to deserialize, because it contains several of properties like it and they just have different types and others have mostly primitive types. I have no access to GameObject class, it is part of Unity.

Comment: I narrowed the issue a bit. It seems to be bypassing my '[CanConvert]' a replacing it with it's own. When I add the attribute to a string, it gets to '[JsonRead]'.

Comment: I am unsure if you were running into the same problem I was, but I found that if my constructor and member variable shared the same variable names, then it thought my member variable was actually the datatype of the constructor variable.

In my case, my member variable and constructor variables were two different types.

Try changing the name of your gameObject to something else that noone would ever use and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

When I did this sort of thing, I created a JsonSerializerSettings  object

```
 var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
 {
     ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
     DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
     NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
 };
 settings.Converters.Add(new Converter());
```

Then passed that into the deserializer

```
 var json = textReader.ReadToEnd();
 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem,
using `MyObjectConverter : JsonConverter<MyObject>` instead of `MyObjectConverter : JsonConverter` helped me

Also don't forget to specify the converter in the deserialization parameters of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, new MyObjectConverter ())`